# Determine whether a specific frequency is contained in signal

Tags: python, audio, fft, frequency

I need to write a script that has to detect frequencies and find a specific one if it is contained in signal. The problem is that I get a big amount of different freq-s after using the FFT and there is no frequency that should be. For instance, if I just send I simple 440 Hz, find peak and print corresponding frequency, it works good. But if I send high frequency signal with some other noise, it doesn't work. This case is more interesting to me.

What am I doing:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft

fs, data = wavfile.read('./signal.wav')
frs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data))
res = abs(frs*fs)
```

In res I can see a lot of "extra" frequencies. The main task is to detect if a specific frequency is in there. 21487 Hz, for example. I've also found the implementation of Goertzel algorithm, but it takes to much time. Is there a fast and simple way to solve my problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The "big amount of different freqs" is created by the noise.  Check to see if the wave file actually contains that high frequency.  It may not if f0 is near Fs/2 due to anti-alias filtering.

Comment: Well, in order to check it, I generated high frequency signal and used a mobile application which showed caught frequencies. The freq-cy I sent, 15342 Hz, was there.

Comment: Equivalently implemented Goertzel algorithm is faster than an FFT.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the np.fft.fftfreq command it only returns a frequency vector of the frequency bin and not the fft of the signal.

To find a frequency in the signal you have to do an fft and then search for example for the maximum in the vector and then calculate back witch frequency that is. Or you then know the position in the vector and you can look the frequency up in the res vector.

Because fftfreq don't calculate an fft it's much faster then to calculate the Goertzel algorithm.

[Description of np.fft.fftfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html)

Comment: Searching for the maximum doesn't solve the problem, as 1. there are a lot of values there. 2. there is noise. So taking max value can return wrong another frequency, not the one I want to see.

Comment: That's true, max is maybe not the best. But i think the problem in your case is, that fftfreq don't calculates the fft of your signal.
When you calculated your fft you know in witch bin the desired frequency is and then you could check if the value is above a threshold or not. (Maybe you have to check additionally the neighbor bins when your frequency doesn't lie exactly in the one bin)

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried to call fftfreq(fft(data)), found values more than some threshold then found indexes as  abs(fft(data)) > threshold and found peaks. But it still doesn't work properly with high frequencies.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem.
Is the sampling rate high enough? (fs>2*21487 Hz)

Comment: Of course, fs is more than 2*f. I think, it is just difficult to detect a specific high frequency in a wav file with a lot of noise..